# Grocery CRUD - ‘text’ Adapt to the screen

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I want `text` can adapt to the screen, because this web page have to run in mobile web browser. I think no need to purchase bootstrap theme, just need to change some `CSS` code in CI framework to change the `text` size to small one that can adapt mobile screen.

This is in PC web browser showing, can adapt to the screen
[image]

But if run it in mobile web browser, it will show like this, can not adapt to mobile web browser
[image]

Could you see the red round in the picture, that place not inside mobile web browser
[image]

Comment: what do you expect ?, its flexigrid theme, there is something called bootstrap theme, which is mobile friendly too, but not free

Comment: @ Akshay responsive style

Comment: @Yuyang you need to checkout bootstrap which make your form resize according to the screen size, you will find bootstrap tutorials easily on google or youtube

Comment: I want text column show half enough, because the text  length to long, not inside the mobile screen already

Comment: @shashi what is responsive style, how I change it?

Comment: @shashi but bootstrap theme need to purchase $12 isn't it? I think this my project just need to change some CSS code

Comment: @3161993 Yes, I know the bootstrap theme, but in my project I think just need to change some CSS code, but not sure how to change